# Ajuda com lógica - PHP

Tags: php

Preciso fazer o seguinte cálculo:

```
(tempo protocolo1 * qtd protocolo1) + (tempo protocolo2 * qtd protocolo2)+ (tempo protocolo3 * qtd protocolo3)
```

Até o momento sem sucesso. Ex:

```
┌──────────┬──────────┬─────┬──────────┐
│ Protocol │ Tempo    │ Qtd │ Total    │
├──────────┼──────────┼─────┼──────────┤
│ TP1      │ 00:30:00 │  2  │ 01:00:00 │
├──────────┼──────────┼─────┼──────────┤
│ TP2      │ 01:00:00 │  3  │ 03:00:00 │
├──────────┴──────────┼─────┼──────────┤
│                     │Total│ 04:00:00 │
└─────────────────────┴─────┴──────────┘
```

Não consigo chegar nessas 4 horas.

```
<?php

        //hora de producao total
        $acumulador="00:00:00";
        for ($i=0;$i<count($_POST['protocolos']);$i++){


        $qtd_protocolos2 = $_POST['protocolos'][$i];
        $siglas2 = $_POST['siglas'][$i]; //id_protocolo


            //pegar tempo do protocolo atraves da ID (sigla)
             $selecionar_tempo = $pdo->prepare("SELECT tempo_protocolo from protocolo where id_protocolo=:id_pro");
             $selecionar_tempo->bindParam(':id_pro',$siglas2, PDO::PARAM_INT);
             $selecionar_tempo->execute();

             $prot_tempo = $selecionar_tempo->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
             $tempo_protocolo = $prot_tempo->tempo_protocolo;


            $tp = strtotime($tempo_protocolo);

            $tp_segundos = strtotime('1970-01-01 '.$tp.'UTC');

            $acum = strtotime($acumulador);

            $acum_segundos = strtotime('1970-01-01 '.$acum.'UTC');


            $acum_segundos =abs((pow($tp,$qtd_protocolos2))+$acum_segundos);



    }
?>
```

Comment: `00:01:00 * 3` = Não seria 3 minutos? '-'

Comment: Digitei errado aqui. Consertado. Obrigada

Comment: Você pode fazer isso na própria consulta sql, qual o banco que você usa?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seu cálculo provavelmente está dando erro pois você está utilizando a função `pow` *(que é a base elevada ao expoente)*. O correto é fazer a multiplicação simples mesmo. `$tp * $qnt_protocolos2` e assim você obtém o resultado desejado.

```
$tp = 3600; // Total de segundo desde 1970-01-01 00:00:00

echo pow( 3600, 3 ); //Saída: 46656000000 (Incorreto) | "pow" retorna (3600 * 3600 * 3600)
echo 3600 * 3;       //Saída: 10800 (Correto)
```

Mas... Deixo aqui uma outra forma de calcular esses valores.

---

Você pode utilizar as classes `DateTime` e `DateInterval`.

A classe `DateTime`, irá nos auxiliar com a adição, subtração etc de datas. Já a classe `DateInterval`, ficará responsável por criar um intervalo de tempo para que possamos fazer os cálculos necessários.

> Irei usar um *array* simples, portanto será necessário que você adapte em seu projeto.

**Código completo e comentado:**

```
<?php

/* Define os protocolos com os tempos o quantidade */
$protocolos = [
    'tp1' => [
        'tempo' => '00:30:00',
        'qnt'   => 2
    ],
    'tp2' => [
        'tempo' => '01:00:00',
        'qnt'   => 3
    ],
];

/* Cria uma data com o "timestamp" 0 */
$date = new DateTime("1970-01-01 00:00:00");

foreach($protocolos as $protocolo => $valor) {

    /**
     * Captura o total de segundos ocorreu  entre
     * `1970-01-01 00:00:00` e `1970-01-01 "tempo_do_protocolo"`.
     */
    $tempo = strtotime("1970-01-01 {$valor["tempo"]}") * $valor["qnt"];

    /**
     * Criamos um intervalo de segundos e somamos com a data da variável indicada
     */
    $date->add( DateInterval::createFromDateString("{$tempo} seconds") );
}

var_dump( $date->format("H:i:s") );
```

[**Demonstração no IdeOne**](https://ideone.com/TRSpLD)

Comment: Eu optei por deixar a resposta mais simples possível, mas caso tenha dúvida de como funciona, posso detalhar alguns pontos.

Comment: Consegui implementar! Obrigada.

Answer (score 1):

Você pode fazer a consulta direto na query sql, por exemplo no MySQL:

```
SELECT SEC_TO_TIME(SUM(TIME_TO_SEC(tempo) * $qtd)) FROM protocolo
```

`TIME_TO_SEC()` - Converte o tempo em segundos

`(tempo * $qtd)` - Faz a multiplicação do tempo (em segundos) vezes a quantidade em cada linha

`SUM()` - Soma os resultados de todas as linhas

`SEC_TO_TIME()` - Transforma os segundos retornados em tipo time (hh:mm:ss)

`$qtd` seria a variável que vem do formulário e `tempo` a coluna do banco

Comment: A quantidade não está em tabela, vem de um formulário. Apenas o tempo está.

Comment: Editei a resposta

Comment: Testei mas não funcionou.

Comment: Coloca como você fez